# counting number of tags in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have sections divided as the following:

```
<div class="section3">
</div>
<div class="section4">
</div>
<div class="section5">
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="section104">
</div>
```

How can a locate what the number of these tags given that I only now the class name will be sectionX, where X is unkown. I'm assuming here that the number will run from 1 to N and there won't be any gaps. Is there an easy way to return this number. I've tried:

```
var elements = $('.section').length;
```

But I suspect I need a way of looping through every div tag that contains 'section' and +=1, which I don't know how to do. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a attribute starts with selector

```
var elements = $('div[class^="section"]').length;
```

**but note that if you add another class value to the element the selector can fail**

As a fair solution I would recommend you add another class to all the elements like

```
<div class="section section3">
</div>
<div class="section section4">
</div>
<div class="section section5">
</div>
```

then

```
var elements = $('.section').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to achieve your need, Please refer [this.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

<s>alert($("div[class^='section']").size());</s>

sorry size was  `Deprecated`. Please use the below instead.

```
alert($("div[class^='section']").length);
```

[<s>DEMO</s>](http://jsfiddle.net/FrjcQ/)

[DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/FrjcQ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/V27Tw/

```
alert($("[class^=section]").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try [jQuery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
$("div[class^='section']").length
```